# How to find normal vector of a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The normal vector of $z = x^2 + y^3$ at $(3,1,10)$. I know $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}(3,1,10) = 2x = 6$ and $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}(3,1,10)  = 3y^2 = 1$, but how do I get $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{z}}(3,1,10)$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial z}{dz}$ is I guess, $1$.

Comment: You are getting your notation mixed up: it should be $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \text{ instead of } \frac{\partial z}{dx}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x,y,z)$ define a surface that is differentiable at a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, then the tangent plane to $F( x, y, z )$ at $( x_0 , y_0 , z_0 )$ is the plane with normal vector
$$
          \nabla F(x_0,y_0,z_0)
$$
that passes through the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. In Particular the equation of the tangent plane is
$$
       \nabla F(x_0,y_0,z_0) . < x - x_0 , y - y_0 , z - z_0 >  =  0
$$

In your case, $\nabla F(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (6, 3, -1)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^3 - z$.  Then $\nabla f = (f_x, f_y, f_z) = (2x, 3y^2, 1)$.  Your surface is the level curve $f(x,y,z) = 0$, so its normal vector is $\nabla f(3,1,10)$.

Answer (score 0):

yaa: a normal to $(x,y,f(x,y))$ is $(-f_x,-f_y,1)$, in our case $(-2x,-3y^2,1)$ at $(x,y)=(3,1)$ it's $(-6,-3,1)$.